# DecimalField in rest_framework 2.4.x and 3.1.x

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i read [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/582) that the representation of a DecimalField in the version of 2.1.16 has been changed from float to string .

My current version is *2.4.x* and a DecimalField is represented as a string which is good for me. However testing now the latest version (*3.1.1*) a DecimalField gets represented as float instead of string .

According to [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/) by default it should be string instead of float .

Even setting this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK['COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING'] = True / False
```

i still get floats. Is there any (other) way to force string output for DecimalFields ?

I' d need some global solution.

Thanks.

-----EDIT-----

```
class FakeView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        balance = {'id': 5, 'name': 'apple', 'value': Decimal(2.5)}
        return Response(data = balance)
```

## v2.4.3:

```
{
    id: 5,
    value: "2.5",
    name: "apple"
}
```

## v3.1.1:

```
{
    id: 5,
    value: 2.5,
    name: "apple"
}
```

so the difference is the type of the *value* value, and i' d like to have str type in v3.1.1 as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry, should be done by now.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `repr(YourSerializer())` so we can see if anything strange is happening with the generated `DecimalField`?

Comment: @KevinBrown: Maybe i was wrong with my question. I' ve this problem when it doesn' t go through a serializer. I updated the question itself.